# Database times out waiting for a free available connection

Tags: java, mysql, database, scala, playframework-2.0

I'm using Java to Play framework version 2.3.7, when I try to call a stored procedure throws this exception:

> [**error**] application - An error has been occurred tryning loading the Pictures by Gift.
>   Timed out waiting for a free available connection.
>   java.sql.SQLException: Timed out waiting for a free available connection.
>   at com.jolbox.bonecp.DefaultConnectionStrategy.getConnectionInternal(DefaultConnectionStrategy.java:88) ~[bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
>   at com.jolbox.bonecp.AbstractConnectionStrategy.getConnection(AbstractConnectionStrategy.java:90) ~[bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
>   at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.getConnection(BoneCP.java:553) ~[bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
>   at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:131) ~[bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
>    - at play.api.db.DBApi$class.getConnection(DB.scala:66) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]

**Java Code:**

```
CallableStatement cst = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
Connection conn = DB.getConnection();
List<Picture> pictures = null;
try {
    conn = DB.getConnection();
    for (Gift gift : giftList) {
        cst = conn.prepareCall("{CALL sp_set_pictures_LOAD_PICTURES_BY_GIFT(?)}");
        cst.setInt(1, gift.getId());
        rs = cst.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            pictures = new ArrayList<Picture>();
            do {
                Picture p = new Picture(rs.getInt(1));
                pictures.add(p);
            } while (rs.next());
            gift.setPictures(pictures);
        }
    }           
} catch (Exception e) {
    Logger.error("An error has been occurred tryning loading the Pictures by Gift.\n" + e.getMessage(), e);
} finally {
    if (cst != null)
        cst = null;
    close(conn);
}
```

**application.conf:**

```
db.default.autocommit=true
db.default.isolation=READ_COMMITTED
db.default.partitionCount=2
db.default.maxConnectionsPerPartition=5
db.default.minConnectionsPerPartition=5
db.default.acquireIncrement=1
db.default.acquireRetryAttempts=10
db.default.acquireRetryDelay=5 seconds
db.default.connectionTimeout=20 second
db.default.idleMaxAge=10 minute
db.default.idleConnectionTestPeriod=5 minutes
db.default.initSQL="SELECT 1"
db.default.logStatements=false
db.default.maxConnectionAge=1 hour
db.default.queryExecuteTimeLimit=1 second
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `DB.getConnection()` twice. Perhaps because of this the JDBC driver creates 2 connections, but you close only the second one.

Comment: thanks , i realized i never close the connection. little detail